# How can Poplar codelets include code from other header files?

Tags: ipu, poplar

Is it possible for codelets to reference code in other files, like header files?

If I have a codelet file

```
    //FileA.cpp
    #include "FileB.h"
    class SomeCustomVertex : public Vertex { 
    public:
       bool compute() {
          int a = SomeConstantDefinedInFileB; 
       }
    ... 
    }
```

and some other "codelet" file

```
    //FileB.h
    const int SomeConstantDefineInFileB = 42;
```

and in the host graph program:

```
graph.addCodelets({"codelets/FileA.cpp", "codelets/FileB.h"});
```

I get a compile error from `popc`:

```
fatal error: 'FileB.h' file not found
#include "FileB.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'poplar::graph_program_compilation_error'
  what():  Codelet compilation failed (see compiler output for details)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured this out.

`Graph::addCodelets` has a parameter `StringRef compileFlags = ""`, which you can use to inject compiler options.

`popc --help` shows an option

```
-I arg                        Add directory to include search path
```

So when I use `graph.addCodelets({"codelets/FileA.cpp"}, "-I codelets");` in the host program, and have my codelets in 'codelets' subdirectory, this works. No need to explicitly list the ".h" files in the arguments.

Incidentally, also a good way to ensure compiler optimisation (`-O3`) for the custom codelets.

Comment: For reference the relevant part of the documentation on `addCodelets` is [here](https://docs.graphcore.ai/projects/poplar-api/en/latest/poplar_api.html#_CPPv4N6poplar5Graph11addCodeletsE9StringRef15CodeletFileType9StringRef).